# Maven M2Eclipse plugin not working

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

Hi I have a strange problem I can not solve on my own. I am trying to use Maven in Newest Spring Tool Suite. I got it working without any problems on my laptop but it doesn't work on my pc (windows 7). On both I have the same version of STS, Maven and other plugins like GWT etc.

The problem is that on PC maven has connection problems (Unable to update index for central|https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) - that is a massage I saw earlier unfortunately I can not reproduce it now it continoiusly tries to update but nothing happens even after 2 hours of waiting (laptop updates within seconds from eclipse start) Both computers use same router, same network, same connection type wifi. I disabled all firewalls etc.

Second problem is that I want to use GWT-maven-plugin to start project. Eclipse had no problem in  adding the archetype but when I try to actualy set up a maven project with this archetype this error occurs in errorlog:

Error downloading archetype org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0

Stack:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizardArchetypeParametersPage.loadArchetypeDescriptor(MavenProjectWizardArchetypeParametersPage.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizardArchetypeParametersPage.setVisible(MavenProjectWizardArchetypeParametersPage.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1229)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.access$4(WizardDialog.java:1208)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$8.run(WizardDialog.java:1197)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1194)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizardArchetypePage$13.open(MavenProjectWizardArchetypePage.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:854)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1168)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.closeZipFile(DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.isFileSetArchetype(DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.isFileSetArchetype(DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.archetype.ArchetypeManager$1.call(ArchetypeManager.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.archetype.ArchetypeManager$1.call(ArchetypeManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1355)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.archetype.ArchetypeManager.getRequiredProperties(ArchetypeManager.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizardArchetypeParametersPage$RequiredPropertiesLoader.run(MavenProjectWizardArchetypeParametersPage.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Root exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.closeZipFile(DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.isFileSetArchetype(DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.isFileSetArchetype(DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.archetype.ArchetypeManager$1.call(ArchetypeManager.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.archetype.ArchetypeManager$1.call(ArchetypeManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1355)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.archetype.ArchetypeManager.getRequiredProperties(ArchetypeManager.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizardArchetypeParametersPage$RequiredPropertiesLoader.run(MavenProjectWizardArchetypeParametersPage.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
```

I already tried cleaning maven cashe, project, temp, setting up STS from the begining I have no Idea why doesn't it work. I use no proxy etc. I've got similar configuration on my laptop and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though [Maven / Guide to Mirror Settings](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html) states:

> The official Maven 2 repository is at `http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` hosted in the US, or `http://uk.maven.org/maven2` hosted in the UK.

it is actually https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ with a redirection to it. So, avoid the redirection by using the actual URL.